# jCarouselLite: How can I get the values of the currently displayed images?

Tags: jquery, jcarousellite

I want a jCarouselLite gallery to act as scrolling thumbnails and present a larger image next to it by somehow refering to it's currently displayed images (then selecting the first image through an array or similar). How would I approach this?

The current setup -


`$('.carousel').jCarouselLite({

 btnNext: '.next',

 btnPrev: '.previous',

 auto: true,

 timeout: 500,

 speed: 500,

 vertical: true,

 visible: 3,

 circular: true,

 beforeStart: function(a) {

 //alert("Before animation starts:" + a);

 },

 afterEnd: function(a) {

  //fetch first image of the currently displayed images

//set html content of .display div to be that of the new image

 }

});`

Answer (score 0):

This might help - [Showing the position in jCarouselLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557870/showing-the-position-in-jcarousellite)

You can use the built in afterEnd and beforeStart functions to show you what's currently being displayed to the user.

```
$(".ccvi-carousel").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: ".next",
    btnPrev: ".prev",
    speed:  800,
    //auto: 2000,
    afterEnd: function(a) { 
        //look into the object and find the IDs of the list items
        left = $(a[0]).attr("id");
        mid = $(a[1]).attr("id");
        right = $(a[2]).attr("id");
        //Do something
        $('li#' + left + ' .cf-img').fadeIn();
        //alert("Left:" + left + "Middle:" + mid + "Right:" + right + "");
    }
});
```